# Gmail stopped redirecting to Inbox

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I have enabled the feature for redirecting Gmail to Inbox, but after a new Gmail (new looks and features) arrived this redirection stopped.

I checked settings in Inbox, but setting for redirection is removed from Inbox.

Any help?

Comment: My meaning is after new gmail, i.e. gmail changed their looks and some features after this my inbox stops working.

Comment: You know they're shutting down Inbox, right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they've disabled the feature. That setting used to lie here:

[image]

But no longer exists.

I've searched the setting in Gmail but no luck.

In Inbox, there's a "Help & Feedback" option on the left. You can request that they reinstitute the feature there.

Comment: There's no point in asking for that. They're shutting down Inbox.